# Accessing method in test class (missing directive or assembly reference)?

Tags: c#, methods, static, void, accessor

I'm only in my basics c# programming and I'm currently stuck with the following problem.

I keep getting the error saying "missing directive or assembly reference.

test class:

```
public void method1()
{
      //forwhile loop

      int num = 0;

      while(1<11)
      {
      Console.Write ("The num is ");

      Console.WriteLine (num);

      num++;
      }
}
```

main class:

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
      method1 mtd = new method1();
      mtd.method1();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `new` operator is never used on method names. It is used with class name to create its object.

  ```
  method1 mtd = new method1(); // WRONG
  ```

in place of `method1` you should use the class in which it is enclosed.

- Your while condition is not correct, (is it type)

  ```
  while(1<11) // WRONG
  ```

it should be `while(num < 11)`

All your methods should be enclosed within classes. I guess, you are confusing method with class.

For example:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

`MainClass` is the class and `Main` is a method within. You can do `new MainClass()` but never do `new Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create object of a method.

Do like this:-
**test class:**

```
public class Test
{ 
    public void method1()
    {
       //forwhile loop

       int num = 0;

      while(1<11)
      {
      Console.Write ("The num is ");

      Console.WriteLine (num);

      num++;
      }
   }
}
```

**main class:**

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
      Test obj = new Test();
      obj.method1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
ClassName cls = new ClassName();
cls.Method1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 'new' keyword on methods. 'new' keyword is used to create instances of the class.

You can place the method within a class(Test), and in 'main', create an instance(t) of that class, and call that method using that instance(t) :

```
public class Test

 {

   public void method1()

   {

      int num = 0;

      while(1<11)
      {
        Console.Write ("The num is ");

        Console.WriteLine (num);

        num++;
      }
    }
 }      

static void main(string[] args)
{
   Test t = new Test();
   t.method1();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using wrong condition in while

```
while(1<11) //this is wrong
while(num<11) //this is right ..
```

try with this